# Were tiles traditionally/originally blue?

Tags: etimología

I discovered on Memrise that "azulejar" means "tile". Why? Were tiles originally blue, or what is the etymology or "back story" of this?

Comment: Note _azulejar_ is _to tile_ and _azulejo_ is a _tile_.

Comment: There is a bird called _azulejo_, whose color is blue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no relationship with the word "azul".

Instead, this comes from the Arab etymology of the word, as stated in the [Wikipedia page for azulejo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azulejo#cite_note-2):

> Azulejo o ladrillo azulejo (del árabe hispano «azzuláyǧ[a]», y a su
>   vez del árabe الزليج az-zulaiŷ, "barro vidriado")

Which is different also from the origin of the word "azul" that DRAE mentions:

> **[azul](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4hL0yKW)**
>
> Quizá alterac. del ár. hisp. *lazawárd*, este del ár. *lāzaward*, este
>   del persa *laǧvard* o *lažvard*, y este del sánscr. *rājāvarta* 'rizo
>   del rey'.

More generally, whenever you see a Spanish word related to construction, engineering or science that starts with `al`, `az`, chances are that it comes from the Arab.

See for example [Palabras de origen árabe](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2008/palabras-de-origen-arabe/) for a nice list of them.

---

If most of the azulejos are blue is because of the influence of the Ming porcelain that Dutch travelers and merchants would import in the XVI century. Their colour had a very good reputation, so people started to mimic its colour in the tiles with the so-called *blue Delft*.

Funnily enough, word and colour ended up being "together" in Spanish : )

Comment: The wikipedia English version does not say  "barro vidriado" but **'The word azulejo is derived from the Arabic الزليج (az-zulayj): zellige, meaning "polished stone" '**.  Anyway, same Arab origen.